# Mail current page as an template - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I need to mail the current page as a template using `mailto:` function in HTML, JavaScript. I can even able to attach a file using `mailto:` function. But I have no idea about to how to create the current page as a template and attach it to the mail. Help me to do this.

Comment: You can grab the current page via document.getElementsByTagName('html').innerHTML or document.body.innerHTML if you only want the body. After for the attachement part I have no idea.

Comment: What do you mean with _"as a template"_?

Comment: You can't arbitrarily mail pages as a template. There's all kinds of dependencies behind the scenes, plus you'll need to inline your styles to ensure they work across all clients (not to mention a text-only version for clients with HTML disabled)

Comment: You probably mean passing HTML to the `body` parameter, but that isn't possible, I think.